# Google CAPTCHA - able to submit a form without checking the box

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha

So I've inserted the Google Captcha validation script to my webform using the official documentation which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Despite me following the documentation to the letter, why am I still able to submit a form without checking the Captcha box? Forgive my arrogance by I thought the whole idea of this CAPTCHA service was that the user would not be able to submit a form without checking the CAPTCHA box so the webmaster can weed out the bots?

The end result **looks** fantastic, I have the CAPTCHA box on my website but right now, you may as well ignore it.

I don't see the point of Google investing time in writing documentation for this script when you can still use a form without the need to check the box. They may as well just not write said documentation because the result is still the same: scratching my head and confused.

Below is the code with ***only the relevant part*** of my form. Can anyone shed any light on what I'm missing here, then whoever can help should definitely consider a career writing coding help documentation for Google because clearly the individuals they employ at the moment - well - need I saw more?

Many thanks and all the best,

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
  <body>

    <form action="<PHP File Directory>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<key>"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this jquery function to check whether captcha is clicked or not before submission.  Otherwise you have to validate the same after form submission. You will have to apply id to the form.  Also place a div with class 'msg-error' just above recapthca div in the form.

```
// to enable recaptcha click validation before form submission
var form = $('#contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var $captcha = $('#g-recaptcha-footer' ),
        response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        console.log(response);

        if (response.length === 0) { console.log("captcha not clicked)");
          $( '.msg-error').html( "<div class='alert alert-danger mb-0 pb-0' role='alert'>  reCAPTCHA is mandatory!</div>" );
          if( !$captcha.hasClass( "error" ) ){
            $captcha.addClass( "error" );
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          $( '.msg-error' ).text('');
          $captcha.removeClass( "error" );

          form.unbind('submit').submit();
        }  
});
```